# how to disable tinymce vuejs

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

i added disabled and readonly but its not working

```html
<tinymce  v-model="Description" :plugins="plugins" :toolbar1="toolbar1" :toolbar2="toolbar2"
                                             :readonly="readonly"
                                             :disabled="readonly"
                                             :other="otherOptions">
                                    </tinymce>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, it depends of the value given to your `readonly` variable, if it's `truthy`.

The example in [the docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#disabled) should be working fine.